# Trying to connect Bigquery via IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, jdbc, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have installed a Database Navigator plugin in order to make connection to google bigquery.

I have downloaded the driver "`SimbaJDBCDriverforGoogleBigQuery42_1.2.2.1004`" and has configured connection string URL as:

```
jdbc:bigquery://https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2:443;ProjectId=xyz;OAuthType=1;OAuthServiceAcctEmail=project-service-account@xyz.iam.gserviceaccount.com;OAuthPvtKeyPath=C:\Users\vikrant\Downloads\GCP-Key\xyz-3d8b203f3315.json;
```

I am not able to connect and every time a window pops up and asking for an Authorization code. Not sure what exactly need to put here.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL will prompt you to authenticate with Google when you open it, which then in turn will give you an alpha-numeric code. Copy and paste the code in the text box.

Comment: Every time I open same project it keep asking me authorization key and the key keeps on changing. Is it reoccurring process to follow?

Comment: Every time you "break the connection" you will need to auth again. Think of it as a security measure. It's like doing auth for your email. Maybe a service account key would be a good way to auth but I am not sure if that connector allows it.